# How to extract data with Actual Column Size rather then Fixed Column Size in SYBASE by ISQL query

Tags: isql

ISQL command executes the SQL file and generates a text file. The results data columns size is based on the fixed size of the column and not based on the actual size of the data. 
e.g. 
The Table "STUDENT" has columns 
"FirstName" varchar(10)
"LastName"  varchar(10)

ISQL Command :-
isql -UUserID -PPassword -SDatabase1 -DUserID -iName.sql -b -s -w2000 -oName.txt

When I execute the SELECT query(Name.sql) by the ISQL command it result in 
Actual :-
FirstName |LastName
JOHN______|DOE_______

Note : "_" is blank spaces

Expected :- 
FirstName|LastName
JOHN|DOE

I did google and I got few links but they were not helpful to me.
https://docs.faircom.com/doc/isql/32422.htm
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/utility14.htm

Installed SYBASE version : 15.7.0

Answer (score 0):

After researching I came to know that Sybase ISQL has this limitation and data result column is based on the fixed size of the column  rather then the actual size.
There are other options available like having temporary table/views and we can get the desired data.
I ended up writing a utility that does the job for me.